# What are the differences between lazy, greedy and possessive quantifiers?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9.3

How do the following quantifiers differ - with respect of scenarios, speed, etc.

- `?`, `??` and `?+` all match **0 or 1 times**.
- `*`, `*? and`*+` all match **0 or more times**.
- `+`, `+?` and `++` all match **1 or more times**.

---

- `?`, `*` and `+` are **greedy**.
- `??`, `*?` and `+?` are **reluctant/lazy**.
- `?+`, `*+` and `++` are **possessive**.

Can anyone help me to understand what these terms mean? Why are there three variations of each quantifier for the same job?

Comment: Why? Because someone somewhere uses them? You really need to take the time to read through the regex documents, and try things using IRB, or rubular.com, see how they work, and remember what you learned for the future. A lot of learning to program is experimentation to observe the effects of minor changes, not asking people to explain those things.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Comment: @TimPietzcker thanks to you for voting up me. It doesn't matter for me,but down vote causes lock to `new posts` - which is fatal I think. I am least interseted to such votes, but too much intersted you like people who has such a keen concept, to have such concepts. But some `SO` users since couple of days I am seeing much more interested to `down vote` others, without knowing the importance of the questions. It's Ok if you don't understand my `Post`. But when the answer has been posted and when the answer is too much knowledgble,then why not come back to up vote who down voted.

Comment: `Good answers never come until good posts coming` I beleieve.And It is not happening for my cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the string

```
aaaab
```

and see how the following regexes match it:

```
Regex          Submatches
               group 1  group 2  group3
(a?)(a*)(ab)   a        aa       ab
(a??)(a*)(ab)           aaa      ab
(a?+)(a*)(ab)  a        aa       ab
(a*)(a?)(ab)   aaa               ab
(a*?)(a?)(ab)  aa       a        ab
(a*+)(a?)(ab)  aaaa              <Match fails!>
(a+)(a*)(ab)   aaa               ab 
(a+?)(a*)(ab)  a        aa       ab
(a++)(a*)(ab)  aaaa              <Match fails!>
```

**Explanation:**

- `a?` tries to match one `a`, but it's prepared to match nothing if that's necessary for the whole match to succeed.
- `a??` tries to match nothing, but it's prepared to match one `a` if that's necessary for the whole match to succeed.
- `a?+` tries to match one `a`. If it can do that, it will *not* back down to match nothing if that were necessary for the overall match to succeed. If it can't match an `a`, then it will gladly match nothing, though.
- `a*` tries to match as many `a`s as it can, but it's prepared to match fewer `a`s, even nothing if that's necessary for the whole match to succeed.
- `a*?` tries to match nothing, but it's prepared to match just as many `a`s as is absolutely necessary in order for the whole match to succeed, but not more.
- `a*+` tries to match as many `a`s as it can. If it can do that, it will *not* back down to match fewer `a`s if that were necessary for the overall match to succeed. If it can't match even a single `a`, then it will gladly match nothing, though.
- `a+` tries to match as many `a`s as it can, but it's prepared to match fewer `a`s (but at least one) if that's necessary for the whole match to succeed.
- `a+?` tries to match only one `a`, but it's prepared to match just as many `a`s as is absolutely necessary in order for the whole match to succeed, but not more.
- `a++` tries to match as many `a`s as it can. If it can do that, it will *not* back down to match fewer `a`s if that were necessary for the overall match to succeed. If it can't match even a single `a`, then the regex fails.

Comment: At last a comprehensive explanation which goes beyond the usual "one or more, etc", "greedy/non greedy". Prima !

Comment: @tim Excellent! What a explanation you gave just briliant! Love it Liked it! :) `+1` to you!

Comment: @DoLoveSky, Don't troll for up votes please. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation for an explanation how you gain reputation without begging for it.

Comment: @DoLoveSky: You already had my upvote before asking, by the way. Don't worry too much about them. Use that energy to ask better questions (for example, correct spelling and grammar do matter).

Comment: @theTinMan I am begging for that,rather I am trying to understand who down vote me and why? If `no vote` is coming in my post - I have no problem. I didn't post here to earn vote,rather i thnik more serious,knowledgeble persons are present here. Thus I joined this community.Somone's `playing with my post by down voting` , which causes to lock any new posts. That hurts me. Thus I asked the people who answered my post, as he knows the seriousness of my post and thus answered.  That's all. Thank you very much to give me the link to know `what reputation is?`

Comment: You are probably getting down-voted because the questions being asked have not showed much, if any, attempt to figure them out. Rather than down-vote people should vote to close the question, but that's how some people are. You can counter that by improving your questions, showing you've tried to find answers and some samples of code showing what you've done and why you think it didn't work.

Comment: Are the submatches of the fifth regex really correct? The Python statement `re.search(r'(a*?)(a?)(ab)', 'aaaab').groups()` yields `('aa', 'a', 'ab')`. [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/) confirms this.

Comment: @WernerWenzel: Oops, absolutely. Strange how this went unnoticed for >5 years - thanks!